# Can't set default image django

Tags: python, django, image

I was create a profile for user. I done set up all the Media and Static. But when I set default and upload_to in image field, it error not found image. I had try all the different Path image but it doesn't work either. Can someone check the path for me. Thank a lot !

path in setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/images')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

url project:

```
   urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.IndexPage.as_view(),name='index'),
    path('welcome/',views.WelcomePage.as_view(),name='welcome'),
    path('bye/',views.ByePage.as_view(),name='bye'),
    path('about/',views.AboutPage.as_view(),name='about'),
    path('profile/', include('accounts.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

model:

```
    class UserInfoCnc(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profile_pics', default='profile_pics/xinlacho.JPG' ,blank=True
```

forms.py:

```
class UserDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfoCnc
        fields = ('user', 'about', 'face_site', 'ins_site', 'profile_pic')
```

views.py:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    form_class = forms.UserDetailForm
    model = models.UserInfoCnc
    template_name = 'userinfocnc_detail.html'
```

show image in html:

```
<img class='img-thumbnail' src="{{ userinfocnc.profile_pic.url }}" alt="Error load image">
```

file media and static in project:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your view through which you are passing `userinfocnc.profile_pic.url` as a context?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I using default of DetailView

Comment: Edit the question and paste the view.

Comment: @SunderamDubey Can you check it again.

Comment: So, what's the exact problem are you not able to see image or not able to see default image? can you elaborate?

Comment: Does all images are saving perfectly in `profile_pics` folder or not?

Comment: It seem like it can't find the path of the image(Not Found: media/profile_pics/xinlacho.JPG). Even the default image or the images I was try upload in local/admin

Comment: One time only add `default='profile_pics/xinlacho.jpg'` in models and then run makemigrations and migrate command, then check it if it works.

Comment: Seen it doesn't work either. I will upload it on Github. Can u download and check it. https://github.com/NVDungg/CnC_project.git

Comment: yes, upload it.

Comment: https://github.com/NVDungg/CnC_project.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the images file was serving files uploaded by a user and the default images was save in media folder. All you need to do it change the STATIC to MEDIA.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And if you use UpdateView to change the images of user. You must add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >` and the UpdateView will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I think if there is no image it should be set to null=True, with that you can validate if there is an image with 2 options:

Option 1

```
<img src=“{{ object.image.url|default:'/media/default_avatar.jpg' }}">
```

Option 2

```
{% if object.image %}
<img src="{{ object.image.url }}">
{% else %}
<img src="{% static 'default_avatar.jpg' %}">
{% endif %}
```